# Individually colored dropdown menus w/ triangles?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

newbie here.

I'm trying to create drop down menus styled with triangles on top. I want each drop down menu to be a different color, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get each triangle to change... I've searched high and low and I'm not having much luck. If anyone could be of assistance, I'd really appreciate it! Here's what I use to make the triangles.

```
nav ul li ul:after {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -10px;
top: -10px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
content:'';
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid #fff; }
```

Also, like I said, I am pretty new at this so if there's anything funky with my code that I can improve on please let me know... Thanks! :)

https://jsfiddle.net/LtuyhLrr/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add this the bottom of your CSS

```
.menupurple:after {
  border-bottom-color: #dda1d8;
};

.menupink:after { 
    border-bottom-color: #ff5e7e;
}
```

**Background**

The line in your CSS that's currently controlling the triangles' color is the `border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;`

Currently you are overriding the background color the purple and pink menu, but you aren't overriding the color of the border that's creating the triangle.